# Where are the enemy spawn points in Firebase Giant?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Where are all the enemy spawn points in Firebase Giant? Can enemies spawn if you are location at the spawn point?

Comment: -1 explanation please

Comment: Whether or not a spawn generates there depends on if there are players in the area.  Typically enemies always spawn in sections without players, so there's no set spawn point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't set spawn points, enemies will spawn anywhere players aren't.

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely one in the far left of the closed in area looking straight from the extraction zone and at the bottom of the ladder from said area. Prima Guides claims there is one at the extraction zone (marked red 1) and from the cliff side.

[Bioware Social Conversation](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/343/index/10037557)

Having played this map a bunch, I think there's at least 3 more on the right side of the map. I've seen enemies pop up from the edge near the ammo crate near the ramp, and come from the lower area and the high room area.